# What is the id goog_number supposed to do in a blogger post?

Tags: blogger, blogspot, google-identity

While I was checking html code of an my old blogger post, I saw there are two tags that I didn't insert and which I haven't seen before.

```
<span id="goog_123456759"> <span id="goog_123456760">
```

(I changed the first seven digits of the numbers)
What does this goog_number do? Are they to track page views?